# Grails Rest API With Many-to-One Domain Mapping

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I am attempting to create a Restful API in grails with a Many-to-One domain relationship.

Here are my two domains:

Release.groovy

```
package releasemap_api
import java.util.Date;
import grails.rest.*
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat

@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Release {
    String branch
    int build
    String buildUrl
    Date created = new Date() 
    static belongsTo = Component

    static constraints = {
        branch blank: false
        build blank: false, min: 0
        buildUrl url: true , unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        created defaultValue: new Date() 
    }
}
```

Component.groovy

```
package releasemap_api
import grails.rest.*

@Resource(formats=['json', 'xml'])
class Component {
    String name 
    static hasMany = [releases: Release]

    static constraints = {      
        name unique: true , blank: false        
    }
}
```

So the idea is that a component can have multiple releases. I use the following URL Map to access/manage a component and its releases.

```
"/components"(resources:"component") {
    "/releases"(resources:"release")        
}
```

Right now I can perform the usual http verbs (PUT,POST,DELETE,GET) directly against the component and release controllers, but I wish to manage releases through their parent components.

For example, I want to perform a POST against

```
./components/1/releases
```

to create a new release and add it to the component with id 1.

So far I was able to work through the release's GET request so that it functions properly directly and through the component url.

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    if(params.componentId !=null)
    {       
       respond Component.where{
        id==params.componentId.toLong() 
       }.find().releases, [formats:['json']]
    }   
    respond Release.list(), [formats:['json']]
}
```

But I am not sure how to configure the write methods so that releases are mapped properly to their parent components. I am using GORM with a MongoDB database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you likely need to override the `queryForResource()` and `createResource()` methods in your releases `RestfulController`.  You may also find a need to override the `delete()` action to break the many-to-one relationship.  Or, if you post your controllers, I believe it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Since I am adding so much customization I choose not to extend the RestfulController and build my controllers step by step as outlined in the grails documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#restControllersStepByStep

Comment: The `grails url-mapping-report` command will give you a look at the implicit parameters made available via the nested mapping.  In your releases controller, you'll have `params.id` which will be the `Release` id (if any) and `params.componentId` referencing the parent `Component`. In the case of a new release, you could use `params.componentId` in a finder, then call `component.addToReleases(new Release(...))`  Again, not sure if I completely follow.  You might take a look at the default `RestfulController` for guidance. Or post your controller source.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the input and I follow what you are saying. I will try to work through the project some more and update my question if I hit a more definitive issue.